# How to implement javascript's 'escape' function in grails

Tags: groovy

Is there an equivalent of JS 'escape' function in Groovy/Java?

```
escape('hello world') => hello%20world
```

I tried this class: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html, but it didn't work.

Or do i have to implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the UrlEncoder class.
I.E - `URLEncoder.encode 'hello world'`